# Clickhouse not start on red-hat 7.8 with error "DNS error: EAI: Address family for hostname not supported"

Tags: clickhouse

I installed `clickhouse` 21.2.4.6 (from tgz file) on red hat 7.8 and by executing the command

```
"systemctl start clickhouse-server"
```

the clickhouse server does not start and in the error file there are several messages:

> Application: DB :: Exception : Listen [::]: 8123 failed: Little :: Exception.
> Code: 1000, e.code () = 0, e.displayText () = DNS error: EAI:
>
> Address family for hostname not supported (version 21.2.4.6 (official build)).

The `<listen_host> :: 1 </listen_host>` tag is commented in the `config.xml` file and the server ip `<listen_host> ip_server </listen_host>` is configured.

Can you give me some information to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please find and check your `clickhouse-server.service` file in systemd related directories and check how exactly clickhouse-server binary run, check --config parameter

usually you just need edit `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`
and replace `<listen_host>::1</listen_host>` to `<listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>`